# Fruit peeling techniques

Tags: equipment, fruit, knives, knife-skills, peeling

I came across [this](http://startcooking.com/blog/217/How-to-Peel-a-Mango) page (How to peel a mango) while surfing and I found it very interesting. What kind of methods and knives/kitchen gadgets do you use to peel fruits? Are there different tools to peel delicate and heavy skinned ones? According to the answers, I'm planning to buy suggested tools/knives to peel fruits.

Comment: Are there certain fruits you peel often or certain ones you're worried about having the right tool for?

Comment: Questions calling for a "list of X" should always be created as community wiki. I converted this for you.

Comment: @Chad: I'm curious to know what tools and technics are used for different fruits (delicate skinned, heavy skinned). The mango example was a great one for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not one to fall for the "as seen on tv" sales pitches... however, I came across the [Titan Peeler](https://www.titanpeelersale.com/)'s on sale at a Bed Bath and Beyond.

Let's say I have never looked back!  They are absolutely amazing, dishwasher safe and great for peeling anything.

Potatoes, apples, carrots, kiwi, you know it the peeler is great.

Comment: Although, good ole pair of fingers work great for bananas and oranges (if orange is ripe).

Answer (score 1):

Between a good chef's knife, a good paring knife, a standard vegetable peeler and your fingers you can basically peel any fruit you need to.

Some fruits require extra work to peel like having to first score and blanch a tomato to more easily peel the skin off.

I've seen some special hardware for various fruits, but it's so focused on one fruit that it's hard to give any recommendations unless you're going to be peeling a specific fruit very often. Things like apple peelers that spin and cut at the same time come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I use 2 different veggie peelers. One has a smooth blade, and one has a serrated blade. The serrated one is great for some of the "tougher" or thick skinned items. The teeth really get a good bite into the flesh.