# Efficient method to peel raw potatoes

Tags: potatoes, peeling

I know already how I can peel cooked potatoes, e.g. by throwing into ice water. According to a german helpster entry, the shell will be easily removable just by "rubbing". But is there another "instant" method for peeling **raw** potatoes? Instant means, I don't want to just peel faster, as suggested [in this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5581/how-to-peel-potatoes).

---

**EDIT** This German helpster entry I described above mentioned some efficient industry methods - which are unfortunately not very usable in a private sector. E.g. putting the potatoes in a natron solution/leach or putting them into a high steam/pressure environment.

**EDIT2** Sorry for the confusion. I don't want them to boil/cook first; so i want just a raw peeled potato afterwards.

Comment: Most industrial methods use abrasion.  I've seen video out there of people using brushes & power tools to get the same effect : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uo7K6CUCudU .  Most cite ~60 seconds to peel a whole bag, but they videos tend to be jumpy enough that I suspect there are cuts / editing so I don't know if it's accurate.

Comment: This has actually been asked and answered over on [lifehacks.SE]. For other "tricks" like this, you might find their site interesting [here's the exact question](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/5680/how-to-quickly-peel-a-bag-of-potatoes).

Comment: Household priced peeling machines are available, eg http://www.amazon.de/Melissa-646120-Kartoffelsch%C3%A4lmaschine/dp/B0079X0EQ6 :) Btw, it is not a solution of "Natron" (baking soda) but "Natronlauge" which is made from "Ätznatron" (caustic soda).

Comment: @rackandboneman this machine seems like an actual answer, please write it in the answer field instead in a comment.

Comment: @Catija no, it's not the same question. I ask specifically about methods which are **not** using boiling as their first step.

Comment: @toogley the highest voted answer there uses raw potatoes and a toilet brush...

Comment: @rumtscho I assumed suggesting appliances (especially one I do not own myself, not eating much potatoes), not methods was out of scope. But then I guess "use a machine, they're cheap" is a method ;)

Comment: On a tangent: Would a wiki-style question about certain appliances and tools being regionally common/uncommon/unknown be a headache or useful? Opinions wanted since I am divided about starting one...

Comment: @rackandboneman That'd be a good question for [Meta](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/)! :D

Comment: @Catija yes, that's true. but i'm not fully satisfied with this method, so i'll wait a few days, maybe another solution will be suggested.

Comment: I used to serve in temple where i saw that to peel potato they were having machine. All you need it to pour potatoes in machine and also need to add normal water. And you will get peeled potatoes in very quick time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are electrical devices using a tumbler:

http://www.amazon.de/Melissa-646120-Kartoffelsch%C3%A4lmaschine/dp/B0079X0EQ6

(The German name is "Kartoffelschälmaschine" for anyone who wants to research it and doesn't like to read encoded URIs ;)

Interestingly, they are uncommon in the US judging by the amazon offers there- instead, the US knows a lot of electric versions of the "apple peeler/corer/slicer" design (which could probably peel a potato too if it was reasonably round, or a certain amount of waste is accepted).

Comment: It basically looks like a food processor and I am guessing it has an abrasive disc on the bottom instead of a grater on top. Seems perfectly reasonable to me. I bet cuisineart could make a few more dollars if they just made the attachment for their line of food processors.

Comment: Given that there is a known "Karborundverfahren" (seems to be exactly what it sounds like :) ) ....